# What does sudo apt install -y do?

Tags: linux, ssh

I've noticed that some installations for packages include a `-y` in `sudo apt install`. I'm just curious and I've googled this already.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Man pages are your friend: https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

The option `-y` tells `apt-get` to assume the answer to all prompts is yes. When you typically install something, it will ask you if you want to proceed after finding the right packages. With `-y`, you won't need to answer that prompt, the installation will proceed automatically.

Comment: Note: the question was about `apt`, not `apt-get`.